# How can i display product detail page page notes for Selected Store?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, messages

I have notes for 
my store 1 like Delivery:  10 Days,

and I have another store and I need to change notes like Delivery: 20 Days,

The condition like if store 1, Delivery:  10 Days, 
and if store 2, Delivery: 20 Days.

How can I display the message based on the current store?

Comment: Where you want to show this message on PDP page ?

Comment: Below Products name.

Comment: I have already show Delivery : 10 Days for my store 1, now i created second store and same message shown my store 2, how can i display notes based on current store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below code in `view.phtml` after product name and check the current store id by:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

Then in if condition echo your message like:

```
if($storeId ==1){
   echo __('Delivery in 10 Days');
}else{
   echo __('Delivery in 20 Days');
}
```

**Note:** 1 is store Id, You can change it as per your store Id.

Comment: How can i give this condition for one of my Div? I have created Quick link using Div, as you know now i should be create new Div, how can i separate based on current store id.

Comment: Could you please share your div code ?

Comment: Here is the code : https://justpaste.it/72zxl

Answer (score 1):

**You can manage this using two ways:**

1. If Delivery values is Store Wise, **You can create separate `Static Block` for each Store with same Static Block ID**. and Add this Static Block on Product Page.
2. If Delivery values is Store Wise but not common in products also, **You can create one `Custom Product Attribute` and save its value on particular store scope**. and Show this Custom Attribute

Comment: FYI : If we using more number blocks magento getting slow, As much as possible we can solve these kind of things by coding. Thank You for your help.